# Angular: How to change/set current page of jw-pagination?

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm having a problem with jw-angular-pagination. I was adding custom sort function when I found that I have no control over the page of pagination. I wonder how to change selected page to first after sorting?

My code (simplified):

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of pageOfItems">
  // ...
</div>
<jw-pagination class="fadeIn" [items]="affiliates" (changePage)="onChangePage($event)" [pageSize]="pageSize"></jw-pagination>
```

TS:

```
affiliates: any[]; // Let's say there are data already
pageOfItemsAffiliates: any;
pageSize = 10;
currentPage = 1;

constructor() {}

onChangePageAffiliates(pageOfItems: Array<any>) {
  this.pageOfItemsAffiliates = pageOfItems;
}

onClickSort(by: string) {
  this.affiliates = this.affiliates.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.totalBalance > b.totalBalance ? -1 : 1;
  });

  this.pageOfItemsAffiliates = this.affiliates.slice(0, this.pageSize);
  this.currentPage = 1;
}
```

So when I click page 2, then sort, it will show first 10 elements sorted but jw-pagination widget will still be showing page 2 as active (while the truth is it's showing the first page). How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have achieved it with kind of workaround. Simulating click on first page button. This button is disabled while first page is selected but it doesn't seem to be an issue.

```
  changeSelectedPageToFirst() {
    let firstElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('first-item')[0] as HTMLElement;
    let clickFirst = firstElement.children[0] as HTMLElement;
    clickFirst.click();
  }
```

Anyways, still I belive there's some better way to do this?